# MVC 4 IntelliSense is not working in Razor in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET MVC4 and the IntelliSense for Razor syntax is not working for me in the views for the application.

What can I do?

Comment: did you upgrade the application or make a new application?

Answer (score 7):

Also Quoting from

http://sebnilsson.com/1091244048/making-mvc-3-razor-intellisense-work-after-installing-mvc-4-beta/

> After installing the MVC 4 Beta the IntelliSense breaks for
>   Razor-views in MVC 3-applications in Visual Studio 2010. This is
>   stated in the release-notes, but nobody usually reads those.
>
> This time the solution to the problem are actually listed in those
>   release-notes. You need to the explicitly state the version-numbers of
>   the references in your web.config.
>
> Add a new appSettings-entry for explicitly stating the version of
>   WebPages to use:

```
 <appSettings>
     <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
     <!-- ... --> 
 </appSettings>
```

> Then you have to edit your .csproj-file, where you need to find your references to
>   System.Web.WebPages and System.Web.Helpers and makes sure they have
>   the explicit version-numbers like this:

eg:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>  

<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

--

> Hopefully this will be resolved in the
>   final version of MVC 4 or maybe the case is that the references to
>   versions in Razor v1 were just too loose in MVC 3-projects.

Also a similar question
[MVC 3 Visual Studio 2010 Razor Model intellisense not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075821/mvc-3-visual-studio-2010-razor-model-intellisense-not-working)

Also you may need to install [VS 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) .

**Edit**:

Also see ***Required updates*** on this page
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me came that in Views\web.config i was referencing an older version of mvc.
(I migrated my project from V3 from V4)
I updated the version and restarted and i have intellisense now