# .Cshtml is greyed out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

Iam working in MVC 4.0 in VS2010 and the .cshtm looks greyed out and also not showing the intellisense. Even the solution is building without any errors. Any sugessions?[image: Iam attaching the image for your reference]

My Root Web Config File shown below:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GatewaySupportTool-20150810125527;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers></system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages"     publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory    type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  </configuration>
```

[image: Installed MVC versions]

Comment: are you sure you are using Razor view engine?

Comment: Yes i am using Razor..:)

Comment: IN your app settings check if it is like this   <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />

Comment: There are two webconfig file, first reside inside the Views(it does not contain the key which you have mentioned above). Second is the root web config and it does contain the above key.

Comment: add this key to the root web config file

Comment: Look at my comment above it is written that "the Key does contain" in root web config file.

Comment: so I said add this key to the config file , that may be the reason for the intellisense not showing up!

Comment: Added not working..:(

Comment: Can you post your root web.config file to your question please let's have a look at it!

Comment: Did you migrate from MVC3?

Comment: No i did'nt migrate from MVC 3. I've posted my Root web config file.

Comment: Your config file looks fine now, try cleaning the project or restarting your VS.

Comment: I have cleaned and restarted but still not working..:(

Comment: here's another solution by a Poster:- "I fixed it by right clicking on the cshtml file and selecting "View Markup"."

Comment: Is the problem specific to a single view or all of them?

Comment: All of them even when i add new view it still adding in a greyed out style.

Comment: Do you have any other MVC version(other than mvc-4) installed ??

Comment: Don't think so , i've added the picture of installed MVC versions,

Comment: your MVC2 version is interfering with the MVC4 version, i'm sure if you uninstall mv2 and restart the VS it'll work fine! But there has to be another way!

Comment: I don't think so because i did work it on Razor some days before and it was working fine at that time, lately i came across this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it by installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (Installer).
 Please navigate to the link http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23691 to download and install. Once installed, Open the Visual studio and look the problem got solved...:)

Answer (score 0):

Such this problems occurs when you have an **auto updated Visual Studio** or **a migrated project to new version of platform or IDE**. Specially, This is true when you mentioned it's *not showing the intellisense* and we have **parser errors** based on some changes in IDE or project configuration to work with each other perfectly.

When you run VS 2010 the first time on a machine that has had VS 2008 installed on it, it asks you if you want to import your existing VS 2008 profile settings. By default this checkbox is *checked* – which means you by default automatically import your existing settings.

#### Solutions

1. Try to work with the same IDE as you created this project
2. Try to re-install IDE
3. Take a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532888/1743997) to see how to correct unwanted changes
4. Use the **Tools->Options** menu command, select the Text **Editor->C#
   settings**, and then check the two circled check boxes above
   (Auto-list members and Parameter information).  Intellisense will
   then be turned on and work fine.

I wish to solve the problem.